# Force loading RDD from file to memory in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have a demo application that runs a Spark computation. For that it loads an RDD stored in an object file, and then perform some tasks that depends on the user's input.

Loading the RDD using `sparkContext.objectFile()` is a lengthy operation. Since time is an issue, I would like to load it before the demo starts, and only perform the calculations that depend on the input during the presentation. However, Spark's lazy policy leads to only reading the file once the entire computation is triggered.

`RDD.cache()` does not do the trick by its-own. Caching is a lazy operation too.

Is there a way to force-load an RDD from file?

If not, is there a way to speed up RDD load, and/or keep it in memory for future Spark jobs?

Spark version is 1.5 and it runs in a single-node standalone mode. The file is read from the local file system. I can tweak Spark's configuration or these settings if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling `cache()`, call any *action* on your rdd (usually one uses `count()`) to "materialize" the cache. Further calls to this RDD will use the cached version:

```
RDD.cache().count() // this will load the RDD
// use RDD, it's cached now
```

Comment: Does not seem to work as advertised. Is it possible that RDD partitions get evicted from the memory, or not loaded in full?

Comment: Only if you don't have enough memory.. do you? You can check this in the Spark UI (https://<driver-host>:4040/storage/), look for your RDD and check its "Fraction Cached"

Comment: Seems to work, albeit very sensitive to Spark's memory management parameters